# C# - Visual Studio - Export DLL's to EXE File

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, export, exe

I am using Visual Studio Community to make a C# Console Application. After I installed a NugetPacket there are a lot of DLL files being exported to the Release folder, when building my application. Is it there a quick way to export all the dll files into my exe file, so they can be accessed from my application? I am talking about more than 40 DLL files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the dll files are in the same directory as your .exe, they will be able to be accessed with no additional work on your part.
If you are looking to package everything up, you may want to look into creating an installer or a .msi file.